# Address of static variable in class

Tags: c++, static-members, memory-address

If I have a class with a static variable:

```
class A {
  public:
    ...
  private:
    static int var;
}
```

Will multiple instances of `class A` use the same address for the static variable `var`?  If not, will defining the variable as a pointer result in the same address? I.e.:

```
class A {
  public:
    ...
  private:
    static int* var;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All instances of *class* A will share the same instance of `var` regardless. If we look at the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `9.4.2` *Static data members* paragraph *1* says(*emphasis mine*):

> A static data member is not part of the subobjects of a class. If a static data member is declared thread_local there is one copy of the member per thread. **If a static data member is not declared thread_local there is one copy of the data member that is shared by all the objects of the class.**

furthermore paragraph *2* says:

> [...][ Note: Once the static data member has been defined, it exists even if no objects of its class have been created. [...]

Comment: How do I declare/not declare a static data member as thread_local?  I want to make sure the data member is shared by all of the objects of the class

Comment: Reread the answer above :-) **If a static data member is NOT declared thread_local...***

Comment: @AlexBrooks *thread_local* is a specifier like *static* if you don't add it then it will not be thread local, read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) for more information.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thank you.  Just wanted to know for future reference :)

Answer (score 3):

All instances of a class will use the same copy and thereby address of the static variable. If doesn't matter if you declare it a pointer or not.

Answer (score 2):

All instances will see the same address for a static variable as there is only a single instance of that variable (that's the whole point of a `static` variable). Obviously if there is only one instance, it can only exist in one place. And it doesn't matter if it is an `int` or a pointer, for the pointer you just have one instance of the pointer that you can use.